# Upgrade Ubuntu 7.04 to Ubuntu 14.10 on dual boot system using USB stick w/no network

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I have an older laptop that has Windows XP and Ubuntu 7.04 installed with no network connection currently. I can boot either partition using GRUB to select which to load. Since the Ubuntu version is so old I would like to upgrade or install Ubuntu 14.10. There is nothing on the Ubuntu 7.04 installation that has any value, but I don't want to mess up the Windows XP partition.

I've used Universal USB Installer to create a bootable USB with Ubuntu 14.04 using ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso. I am able to boot with the USB flash drive and see a Ubuntu menu. One of the options is to install Ubuntu Server. I tried that option initially, but apparently it needs to download packages over the Internet to perform the install.

Without a network connection the install won't continue.

I assume that there must be a way of including the required packages on the USB flash drive so that network connectivity is not required, but I'm not sure where these setup packages can be found or even where to put them on the USB flash drive.

How can I create a bootable USB flash drive that contains all of the required install packages?

Once I've created the USB flash drive without networking requirements, how do I install to the partition containing my existing Ubuntu 7.04 partition without messing up my Windows XP partition? I am using GRUB. The installation help page has so many different options. One of them is close to what I think I need, but I don't see instructions specifically for installing to an existing Ubuntu partition in a multiple boot scenario.

Comment: just do a fresh install, the upgrade would take forever, take a ton of bandwidth, would be likely to break, and completely unsupported.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, but how? I assume I have to write an .iso to my USB flash drive and then boot from it? I tried that, but the needed files were not on the USB and the laptop has no network connectivity until I receive a new network card I ordered. Are there instructions for this someplace that take into consideration a dual boot system? Or will the setup ask me which partition?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: Check the howto bodhi.zazen linked above and if that doesn't answer your question, [edit] it and provide us with a detailed question to answer! Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I did review the installation help page and the link to the MultiBoot instructions. I am having a difficult time finding the instructions to install to an existing Ubuntu partition without messing up the Windows XP partition. So many warnings, so I'm being cautious. What details can I include in my question that would help you better to point me? Thank you.

Comment: @Fabby I've already installed Ubuntnu. I wish you would have read my question and understood my problem before marking it up with your notes of being a duplicate. I don't claim to be so knowledgeable of Linux/Ubuntnu and I do need help, but your link does not provide me with that help. Couldn't you find a question someplace that you could answer? Everything isn't a duplicate... Or perhaps you could have provided more than a link and explained why you think this is a duplicate question?

Comment: You need download and install the desktop version that will install without network connection, not the server version.  So that's what the duplicate is about. "Required packages" is vague but they can be found here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ The total sum of packages is >250GB so without any Internet connection, you'll have to hand-pick them *and their dependencies*, so **you're looking at an astronomical amount of work.** (couple of days instead of couple of hours)

Comment: Please help us help you identify the partition to install to by booting your Ubuntu installation and [edit]ing your question and adding the the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (run from terminal)

Comment: @karel Your link helped me. Not sure if this helps anyone else, but I had 2 boot partitions - Win XP and Ubuntu 7.04. I was using legacy GRUB. I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.10 desktop .iso and burnt it to my USB flash drive. Booted my laptop from the USB and selected the option to Try Ubuntu. Once loaded, I clicked the Install Ubuntu 14.10 icon on the desktop. This put me through the install wizard. I selected the option to erase Ubuntu 7.04 and reinstall. Everything went well. Looks like my legacy GRUB got replaced, but it's correct and both OS boot fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ElderGeek I recognize your willingness to help. Thank you to you too.